# Android place markers on static image

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I need a placemarker on a static image. Any tutorials to refer? what I have found are usually on google maps instead of static image. I need a placemarker which points to places from a static image.. Thanks. I will need this on an android device

Comment: Superimposing one static image (a placemarker icon) over another (a static map image) is a fairly simple front-end layout task. Is this what you need help with? If not, can you expand on your question?

Comment: @NathanSmith using layouts for such a task is overkill imho

Comment: Hi i need to point some placemarker icons on an image on a map based on location i want. However the map will be a static image. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @user3131408 use LayerDrawable then, it lets you combine several Drawables

Comment: @pskink: No doubt you are right. Apologies, as I am not much of an Android dev, so I am punching above my weight class.

Maybe a [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) would work here?

Comment: @NathanSmith yes LayerDrawable is the best friend here

Comment: Most referances i found is on google map. Is there any on static images you guys can refer? i need to put placemarkers on an indoor location of a map. Thanks

Comment: @user3131408 I think u r looking for this http://joerg-richter.fuyosoft.com/?p=120

Comment: Hello this is what i am looking for. However, on different devices the marker image that i add seem to be different. Anyway for it to be the same? Meaning same image with marker on different devices.